# Character Wise Advance search in AJAX and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have done advance search which match character from front side. I want that it should match with middle and End of the word also or to everywhere in Database. How should i can d that my advance search code is here
PHP code........................

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
  $servername="localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password="";
  $conn=mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
 if (!$conn) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
 }
 
 $in=$_GET['q'];
if(!ctype_alnum($in)){
    echo "Data Error";
    exit;
}

  mysql_select_db('firstdb');
  $sql="select name, id , age, sex from name where name like '$in%' or sex like '$in%' or age like '$in%' or id like '$in%'";
  $display=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
 echo "<table>
 <tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Age</th>
 <th>Gender</th>
 </tr>";
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $display ) ){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sex'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

JS code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function user(str){
    if(str.length==0)
 {
 document.getElementById("userhint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
 } 
 else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("userhint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "advanceSearch.php?q="+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

 
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" onkeyup="user(this.value);" name="username" />
</form>
<br />
<div id="userhint"><b>User info will be listed here...</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to do more clearly?

Comment: @parveen when i write any character in Text it should fetch all records which contain that character irrespective of character position but my above query only match from start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done by little change in query

```html
$sql="select name, id , age, sex from name where name like '%$in%' or sex like '$%in%' or age like '%%$in%' or id like '%$in%'";
```